# How are threads made?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was reading up on threads and as I understand it, they are a set of values for an execution context. From what I understand, a thread is comprised of values (registers, PC, stack, etc.) that allow a CPU to continue running a set of instructions.

However, my question is: how are these threads made? I hear some of my professors throw around the word thread as a way to break up a process into multiple (mostly) independent parts of code (ie. multithreading). How does this work? Is there another section of memory that stores specifically what a thread can run, as well as it's state?

Comment: Essentially, by allocating a Thread Control Block and stack space, initializing and setting them up with values that mimic a ready thread - one that was running before but got interrupted.  The IP 'pushed' onto the stack is the first instruction of the thread.  Push the TCB address onto the ready list, run the scheduler/dispatcher and.....off it goes:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that operating systems vary greatly in their general working as well as in their implementations of seemingly identical functions.
so don't go into these kind of questions thinking that if one operating system does something in some way then other operating systems would do that in similar manner.

Now to your question

> how are these threads made?

I will answer it using Linux as an example. When creating a new process Linux lets you specify which data structures (file descriptors, IO context etc) new process would share with its parent process. you can do this using the [clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) system call. 
you can see in the documentation of clone that it takes some parameters specifying the sharing properties.

Now you can call a task_struct thread if it shares all sharable data structures with its parent ( because this property is consistent with the conventional definition of a thread). and if it shares none then you would call it a process.

But as far as Linux is concerned there is no notion of a thread or a process, all you have is a task_struct which may share certain resources with its parent.